# How do I use my computer as a host for a website - given my IP is static?

Tags: localhost, static-ip

I search online a lot for this but I was not able to find out how.

My ISP gave me a static IP address. Now, I connected this ISP Line to a `DLink DIR-850L` and then put a LAN cable from the router to my system.

I assigned a local static IP to my system.

Now, how do I route traffic to my static IP Address to my local computer?

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D-Link DIR-850L is capable of 24 *port forward* / *virtual server* rules. Read the [user manual](ftp://files.dlink.com.au/products/DIR-850L/Manuals/DIR-850L_A1_Manual_v1.00(DI).pdf), pages 84-85. For a web server, you'd forward TCP ports 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS) to your internal static IP.